# How to create a directory in C directory of Windows7 in C#.Net

Tags: c#

I am writing the exception log (eg. log.txt) and I want to write in the following path "C:\Program Files (x86)\App\Log". When I do so, I get the whole path as access denied which means I cannot create the folder called Log and simultaneously write the log.txt and I have also the compression code to zip the log files like log.zip which is a days based? I did try some of the code snippets from the stack overflow apparently nothing fruitful.

How do I resolve this problem??

Regards,
Gibson

Comment: could also be that the proces dont have access to create folder / files in program files

Comment: "Run as administrator" or write the log somewhere else, because ProgramFiles is not for logging.

Comment: Writing to these directories is only possible with elevated privileges. You should rather write those log files to the appdata folder.

Comment: Have you tried just creating the file without the absolute address? `using(FileStream stream = new FileStream("Log\log.txt"), FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite) using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream)){writer.WriteLine("Log Text");}`

Answer (score 4):

The error you are getting is most likely due to the fact that a regular user doesn't have permission to create folders or files beneath the "C:\Program Files (x86)\" directory.  **This is on purpose** because a regular user should *not* be writing to that directory.

Applications are installed beneath that directory by an administrative user, or a user with elevated permissions.  Your application should be writing log files to a location beneath the user's profile directory, e.g. somewhere beneath "%appdata%".

I work in an IT department where we have to support poorly-written vendor software that needs to update files somewhere beneath the %programfiles% directory, and it's a total nightmare.  We don't want our users to have permission in general to write to that folder because it would potentially allow malicious software -- viruses, etc. -- to surreptitiously modify our applications.  However, we have to make exceptions in our virus software and constantly maintain special security on the folders for this deviant application that, unfortunately, our business relies on.  The point of the story is: don't do it.  It's bad practice, and your customers will not be happy.

Answer (score -1):

- creating folders and files on windows 7 is not open for any users
  only authorized users can create files or folders
- you can either give authority to everyone on the main directory on
  which you want to add folder or you can check in application pool the
  user who is starting iis and give him permission on main folder